# Speakerdeck inside of fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, oembed

## Speakerdeck

 uses a [script to embed](https://speakerdeck.com/faq#oembed) a call which will setup an api and json response, like:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "type": "video",
    "provider_name": "YouTube",
    "provider_url": "http://youtube.com/",
    "width": 425,
    "height": 344,
    "title": "Amazing Nintendo Facts",
    "author_name": "ZackScott",
    "author_url": "http://www.youtube.com/user/ZackScott",
    "html":
        "<object width=\"425\" height=\"344\">
            <param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/M3r2XDceM6A&fs=1\"></param>
            <param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"></param>
            <param name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\"></param>
            <embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/M3r2XDceM6A&fs=1\"
                type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"425\" height=\"344\"
                allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\"></embed>
        </object>",
}
```

Simply placing a Speakerdeck embed link, like:

```
<script async class='speakerdeck-embed' data-id='4ece03012a0554004f008afa' data-ratio='0.9534450651769087' src='//speakerdeck.com/assets/embed.js'></script>
```

works well, but I have not been able to integrate it with [**fancybox v2**](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/). But the problem seems more with running a `a href="script"` than it does with the oEmbed api json within a fancybox iframe.  (But not sure of that.)

So I broke it down to the minimum of just launching the script via an `a href="script"` link - because fancybox uses the a element - I have tried a few variations of:

```
<a href="javascript(async class='speakerdeck' data-id='4ece03012a0554004f008afa' data-ratio='0.9534450651769087' src='//speakerdeck.com/assets/embed.js')" >show it</a>
```

All I've gotten is a spinning loader icon, and worse.

I think I am just having a mental error over the obvious, can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have your `data-id='4ece03012a0554004f008afa'`, it would be as simple as passing it directly into the `href` link via an `embed` method like

```
<a class="fancydeck" href="http://speakerdeck.com/embed/4ece03012a0554004f008afa">CLICK to open speakerdeck inside fancybox</a>
```

Then just use this fancybox custom script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".fancydeck").fancybox({
  type : "iframe",
  width: 640, // or whatever
  height : 420,
  fitToView : false
 });
}); // ready
```

[SEE DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/speakerDeck_02nov12.html)

**NOTE**: I am using fancybox 2.x in my demo but I don't see why not it wouldn't work with v1.3.4

Comment: Thanks for the response, JFK.  I'm using v2 too.  I'll check it out and post back later.  Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: Perfection.  Great advice.  Short, simple and right to the point.  Thanks, JFK.